# Выдает ошибку android.widget.LinearLayout is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

Вроде по документам все правильно, а выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.LinearLayout is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Мой код:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_fragment__coasts,container,false);

    controller = new Controller_Fragment_Coasts ();

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById (R.id.lvCoasts);

    listView.setAdapter (new SimpleCursorAdapter (this.getActivity (),R.layout.info_layout,controller.ReadDateWithDB (this.getActivity ()),
            new String[]{"summa","description","nameCoast"},
            new int[]{R.id.tvSumma,R.id.tvDescription,R.id.tvName}));
    registerForContextMenu (listView);
   //inflater.inflate (R.layout.layout_dialod,container);


   listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            curItem = id;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return v;
   } 



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.anton.familybudget.Fragment.Fragment_Coasts"
android:id="@+id/list">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

   <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:id="@+id/lvCoasts">
   </ListView>


</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/nameCoast"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/summa"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSumma"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: В контейнер LinearLayout (у вас с ID tvDescription) нельзя поместить текст (данные), это можно сделать только в виджеты вроде TextView и его наследников. Очевидно в конструкторе адаптера вам надо указать вместо `R.id.tvDescription` просто `R.id.description` (ID виджета TextView) или поменять имена ID у TextView и LinearLayout в котором он находится.

Comment: Спасибо все верно)